# Deduction of 2nd order ODE general solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions, euler-mascheroni-constant

When I have some ODE, for example:

$$
u''(t) + 5u(t) = 0
$$

I put together a characteristic equation:

$$
\lambda ^2 + 5 = 0
$$

Then I compute its roots $r_1$ and $r_2$.

And now there are some general solutions:

1) If $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb R$ and $r_1 = r_2$, then the general solution is:
$$u(t) = C_1 e^{r_1x} + C_2 e^{r_1x}\cdot x$$

2) If $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb R$ and $r_1 \neq r_2$, then the general solution is:
$$u(t) = C_1 e^{r_1x} + C_2 e^{r_2x}$$

3) If $r_1, r_2 = \pm (a + ib)$, then the general solution is:
$$u(t) = e^{ax}(C_1 cos(bx) + C_2 sin(bx) )$$

---

#### Questions

1) How can I deduce the 3rd formula? I know, that 
$$
e^{a+i b} = e^{a}e^{ib} = e^{a}(cos(b) + i\cdot sin(b)),
$$

but I'm not able to get it to the right form. I've only got this far:

\begin{align}
u(t) &= C_1 e^{i\lambda x} + C_2 e^{-i\lambda x} \\
&=  C_1 cos(\lambda x) + iC_2 sin(\lambda x) + C_2 cos(\lambda x) - iC_2 sin(\lambda x)\\
&= cos(\lambda x)(C_1 + C_2) + sin(\lambda x)(iC_1 - iC_2)
\end{align}

2) I've found in one book, that

$$
u(t) = u(t) = C_1 e^{r_1x} + C_2 e^{r_2x} = C_1 cos(r_1x) + C_2 sinh(r_2x)
$$

And I'm also not able to "prove" it.

Comment: Take the solution you have derived. $C_1,C_2$ are arbitrary. So take $C_1=\frac{1}{2}B_1-\frac{1}{2}iB_2,C_2=\frac{1}{2}B_1+\frac{1}{2}iB_2$, then your solution has the required form. Now try something similar for your Q 2).

Comment: @almagest Oh, thank you! Could you write it as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you correctly got as far as $e^{ax}((C_1+C_2)\cos bx+i(C_1-C_2)\sin bx)$. But $C_1,C_2$ are arbitrary. So take $C_1=\frac{1}{2}B_1-\frac{1}{2}iB_2,C_2=\frac{1}{2}B_1+\frac{1}{2}iB_2$. Then $C_1+C_2=B_1,i(C_1-C_2)=B_2$, so your solution becomes $e^{ax}(B_1\cos bx+B_2\sin bx)$, which has the required form.